# Excel VBA Determining an Upward or Downward Trend

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a program that designates what type of trend a set of numbers is in. Either an Upward Trend, Downward trend, or no trend. Please see my excel style tables below so you can follow along with the next part.

The program needs to calculate Row 3.  Row 3 is going to either have a U (for Up) or a D (for down) or nothing. Below I explain how to designates a U or a D aka this is what I want the VBA program to do for me.

Let's Start at Column C. Column C1 has a value of 34.92, and C2 was given a + (as 34.92 was larger then the day before which was 33.02).  Now we go to the first previous "+" WITH AT LEAST one opposite sign (in this case "-") in between. So in this case that is column A (one "-" inbetween under column B).  Now if the Numerical Value in C1 (34.92) is larger then the numerical value in A (33.12) then we designate a "U" in C3. If it was NOT larger we would leave an empty cell in C3.

Let's move onto column D. Column D1 has a value of 35.19 which is greater then the C1 value of 34.92 and this is why D2 has a "+". Next we go to the first previous "+" WITH AT LEAST one opposite sign (in this case "-") in between. So in this case that is column A again. Since the numerical value in D1 (39.19) is greater then the numerical value in A1 (33.12) then D3 gets a U.

Moving onto Column F (32.97). 32.97 is LESS then 35.19 (D1) which is why F2 is a "-". Next we go to the first previous "-" WITH AT LEAST one opposite sign (in this case "+") in between. So in this case this is column B (with two "+" signs in between). Now because we are dealing with "-" signs this time we look and see if the numerical value in F1 is LESS then the numerical value in B1...which it is, so a "D" is entered in F3. If F1 was larger then B1 then the cell would be left empty.

Onto Column G (35.21). This is greater then 32.97 (F1) and therefore gets a "+" in G2.  Next we go to the first previous "+" WITH AT LEAST one opposite sign in between (in this case "-"). So in this case this is column D (with one "-" in between). Since the numerical value of G1 is greater then that of D1 we designate a "U". If it was not greater we would leave the cell empty.

```
Table 1: Initial Table before Program
        A        B        C        D        F        G        H        I
        Jan 1    Jan 2    jan 3    Jan 4    Jan 5    Jan 6    Jan 7    Jan 8
1       33.12    33.02    34.92    35.19    32.97    35.21    35.60    35.90
2       (+)      (-)      (+)      (+)      (-)      (+)      (+)      (+)
3                          ?        ?        ?        ?        ?        ?

Table 2: Final Table with Answers
        A        B        C        D        F        G        H        I
        Jan 1    Jan 2    jan 3    Jan 4    Jan 5    Jan 6    Jan 7    Jan 8
1       33.12    33.02    34.92    35.19    32.97    35.21    35.60    35.90
2       (+)      (-)      (+)      (+)      (-)      (+)      (+)      (+)
3                          U        U        D        U        U        U
```

```
Sub Comparison()

For Each Cell In Range("A3:I3")
currentSign = cell.Value
' Find out what the sign is in the cell before it
previousSign = Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
'Variable used to find the first cell with an
'Opposite sign as the current cell
oppositeSign = Cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
'Variable to associate the numberical number above the first Opposite Sign Cell
oppositeNumericalCell = Cell.Offset(-1, -2).Value
' Create a Variable for Target Cell
Set targetSignCell = Cell.Offset(1, 0)
If currentSign.Value = "+" And currentSign.Value <> previousSign.Value And oppositeSign.Value = currentSign.Value And currentNumericalCell.Value > oppositeNumericalCell.Value Then
targetSignCell = "U"
ElseIf currentSign.Value = "-" And currentSign.Value <> previousSign.Value And oppositeSign.Value = currentSign.Value And currentNumericalCell.Value < oppositeNumericalCell.Value Then
targetSignCell = "D"
Else
End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Only assertions. Also your most may contain a bit too much information. Trim it to only what is essential to know.

Comment: Also, there's nothing in here which couldn't be achieved in a formula.  Is there a reason why this needs VBA?  Should this be migrated to SuperUser?

Comment: We appreciate that you took the time to format your code and examples properly, but I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: It would help if you could get your terminology consistent - for example "Row A" and "Column C1" make your explanation too difficult to follow.  Unless your writing is super-clear, that's too much to process.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for your interest. Alex I just fixed the question a little...My question is just that my code does not work. James, when the program is looking for "the next "+" sign with AT least one "-" in between (or visa versa), this next "+" sign could be 30 cells before (aka 29 "-" signs in a row). As far as I am concerned a regular formula could not do this.

Comment: Hey Tim! Thanks so much, just changed them all to column. Yes I know it is confusing! I tried to make it as clear as possible!

Comment: This is a lot to digest, but some possible formulas to play would be `Match`  `Index`, `Offset`, `CountIf`, and `IF` statements using `><=`. If you combine some of these with some creative `Absolute` range referencing, you may not need VBA.

Comment: @AlexHunt in terms of technicals you need to share with us where you are getting the data? If you want to build techs on Excel that's not super flexible. As you will be using so many volatile functions your trend will be not worth the time it would take.. you will literally lose the trend if you are to go for any high frequency/short term stuff.. But you can try MLQ4 or MLQ5.. :) The way you articulated your question is thinking the readers will know the domain ;)

Comment: @bonCodigo, the data is actually stock prices. I am retrieving the stock prices from a program called Thompson Reuters.  Basically you can have it input the last X number of trading days (closing prices) into excel.

Comment: This program will decide wether it is in a downward trend or an upward trend. This is just the first part of my "trend analysis" though. Once it determines if it is in a D or an U it further calculates if it is in a Rising, falling or Doubtful trend.  In the end the program will hopefully say which of the Rising/Up rising/Down Rising/Doubtful/Up doubtful/Dow Doubtful/Falling/Up Falling/Down Falling trends it is in

Comment: @AlexHunt Reuters =) Yup the so you are using `3K Xtra` or `PPRo`? Can you tell me which function you are talking about? Simplest is to get the price and last trade date given a stock tickers. and you are downloading last trading date for a particular start date and end date for one stock or multiple stocks?

Answer (score 0):

Lightly tested....

```
Sub tester()
    Dim c As Range
    'loop through the +/- range...
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A3:H3")
        CheckCell c
    Next c
End Sub

Sub CheckCell(c As Range)

    Dim pm As String, v As Double, v2 As Double
    Dim pm_opp As String, c2 As Range
    Dim oppFound As Boolean, pm_tmp As String


    v = c.Offset(-1, 0).Value        'value
    pm = c.Value       'sign
    pm_opp = IIf(pm = "+", "-", "+") 'opposite sign

    If c.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub

    Set c2 = c.Offset(0, -1)

    Do While c2.Value <> ""
        Debug.Print oppFound
        pm_tmp = c2.Value
        If Not oppFound Then
            oppFound = (pm_tmp = pm_opp)
        Else
            If pm_tmp = pm Then
                v2 = c2.Offset(-1, 0).Value
                If pm = "+" And (v2 < v) Then c.Offset(1, 0) = "U"
                If pm = "-" And (v2 > v) Then c.Offset(1, 0) = "D"
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        If c2.Column = 1 Then Exit Do
        Set c2 = c2.Offset(0, -1)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I am quite new to VGA (only 1 week or so!) so I get lost in some of your code. It completely works which is incredbible but I wish I knew how it worked! This first part that stumped me was what does "pm_opp = IIF(pm = "+","-","+")" say?

Comment: To find the opposite sign, it's checking to see if the current sign is equal to "+" - if it is then the opposite is "-", else it's "+".  It's basically a shorthand for `if this then that else other'

Comment: I just posted an answer that has my next section of the programn. It is EXTRMELY similar to the previous problem and thus I thought I could use teh same code actually. But I am getting an error. Would you mind taking a look? Thanks so much!